# How to change the position of image in search box in css?

Tags: html, css

I have been created simple search form, using by google.

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/njs6d489/

In that, search icon right side right?

But i need icon looking left side and placeholder also need to place left side.

I explained in this image http://s22.postimg.org/ype712rcx/Untitled_1.png

May i know, how can i do this. Is there possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #666;
    font: 90%/180% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
    color: #69C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #F60;
}


input {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    display: none; 
}

input[type=search] {
    background: #ededed url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
    width: 55px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
    -moz-border-radius: 10em;
    border-radius: 10em;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 130px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #66CC75;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}


input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}

/* Demo 2 */
#demo-2 input[type=search] {
    width: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#demo-2 input[type=search]:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 130px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: auto;
}
#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: *"In that, search icon right side right?"* - No, I think you swapped left and right.

Comment: yes.. you are right @GolezTrol

Comment: because, i need to place the search box right-corner of my page..

Comment: The image suggests you want to move the icon, but now you say you want to move the whole box. It sounds like two questions in one. Very confusing.

Comment: @GolezTrol: when i click the search icon, then placeholder box now shows left side ok?.. but i need right side.

Comment: When you click the icon, the search box scrolls out to the right. I don't know what you mean by 'placeholder box'. The whole thing is on the left, but it also is before you click the icon.

Comment: @GolezTrol: according my posted jsfiddle, it shows left side on my page.. i need place the right side.. here is my screenshot .http://s28.postimg.org/lts74svzh/Untitled_1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/njs6d489/1/)**

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/njs6d489/4/)**

I changed the search icon's background position at Normal state as 50% and on focus as 90%.

Here I included only the css which I changed.

**CSS:**

```
input[type=search] {
    background: #ededed url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 50% center;    
    float:right;    
}
input[type=search]:focus {      
    background: #ededed url(http://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 90% center;

}
```

Comment: no no @etach: i need search placeholder box totally place left side.. but you did, search icon placed the left side..

Comment: From your image i understood you need search icon on right ride, what do u mean by search placeholder box here..

Comment: simply, i ask a one question. if use my posted jsfiddle link in your web page on the position is right-corner means, how to use.?

Comment: Do you mean you want to place whole search container on right side of your page? if so use float:right;

Comment: I think Etash gives correct answer as per your image. Be clear what you want.

Comment: yes.. and also.. is it possible to rotate the sarch icon image left side?

Comment: try to use different image or flip it using any image editing tool